# class not found exception for application subclass on PC does not work - on MAC is OK

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception

I am trying to bring an Android project from Eclipse Mac to a PC.

While everything now finally compiles - I get a "class not found error" for the application subclass.

This is what I mean with application subclass: (from the docs)

```
android:name
    The fully qualified name of an Application subclass implemented for the application. When the application process is started, this class is instantiated before any of the application's components.

    The subclass is optional; most applications won't need one. In the absence of a subclass, Android uses an instance of the base Application class.
```

This is it in my Manifest:

```
  <application
        android:name="com.xxx.MyClassToBeInstantiated"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        ...
```

Is there anything different on PC?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Real strange - after increasing the memory for Eclipse on the PC this error went away. Probably it just did not compile correctly due to memory limitation.